# Deserialize XML elements to different types, based on attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I have an XML document with many `Entity` elements, which each have an attribute of either `type="foo"` or `type="bar"`. See this sample:

```
<RootNode>
    <Entities>
        <Entity type="foo">
            <Price>1</Price>
        </Entity>

        <Entity type="bar">
            <URL>www.google.co.uk</URL>
        </Entity>

        <Entity type="foo">
            <Price>77</Price>
        </Entity>
    </Entities>
</RootNode>
```

I need a way to tell [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to deserialize the `Entity` elements with `type="foo"` into a `List<FooEntity>` and the elements with `type="bar"` into a `List<BarEntity>`.

How can I do this?

Here is the code I currently have if you want to play around with it:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(
            Paths.get("/path/to/file.xml"),
            Charset.defaultCharset()
        );
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();

        RootNode root = serializer.read(RootNode.class, r);
        System.out.println(root.getFooEntities().size());
        System.out.println(root.getBarEntities().size());
    }
}

@Root(name = "RootNode")
class RootNode {

    // TODO: What annotations to put here?
    private List<FooEntity> fooEntities;

    // TODO: What annotations to put here?
    private List<BarEntity> barEntities;

    public List<FooEntity> getFooEntities() { return fooEntities; }
    public List<BarEntity> getBarEntities() { return barEntities; }
}

class FooEntity {
    @Element(name = "URL")
    private String url;
}

class BarEntity {
    @Element(name = "Price")
    private int price;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the real problem ...

```
// TODO: What annotations to put here?
private List<BarEntity> barEntities;
```

**My answer:** none! Or at least, it doesn't matter!

Attributes like `type` here are just strings and can't make any decisions. But there's another nice way:

1. Implement a Converter for `RootNode` which does the decision
2. Use a `Serializer` to do the actual work of deserializing each entity.

I made some modifications to your classes, but nothing spectacular has been changed. The `toString()`-method is for testing only - implement as you need it.

### Class `FooEntity`

```
@Root(name = "Entity")
public class FooEntity
{
    @Attribute(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Element(name = "Price")
    private int price;

    /*
     * NOTE: A default ctor is required - visibile doesn't matter
     */

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "FooEntity{" + "price=" + price + '}';
    }
}
```

### Class `BarEntity`

```
@Root(name = "Entity")
public class BarEntity
{
    @Attribute(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Element(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    /*
     * NOTE: A default ctor is required - visibile doesn't matter
     */

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "BarEntity{" + "url=" + url + '}';
    } 
}
```

### Class `RootNode`

```
@Root(name = "RootNode")
@Convert(RootNodeConverter.class)   // <--- Important!
class RootNode
{
    private List<FooEntity> fooEntities;
    private List<BarEntity> barEntities;


    public RootNode()
    {
        // This has to be done somewhere ...
        this.fooEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        this.barEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public List<FooEntity> getFooEntities()
    {
        return fooEntities;
    }

    public List<BarEntity> getBarEntities()
    {
        return barEntities;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "RootNode{" + "fooEntities=" + fooEntities + ", barEntities=" + barEntities + '}';
    }
}
```

And finally the `Converter`-implementation:

### Class `RootNodeConverter`

```
public class RootNodeConverter implements Converter<RootNode>
{
    @Override
    public RootNode read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        RootNode root = new RootNode();
        final InputNode entities = node.getNext("Entities");
        InputNode child;

        while( ( child = entities.getNext() ) != null )
        {
            if( child.getName().equals("Entity") == false )
            {
                continue; //  Not an Entity
            }

            final Serializer ser = new Persister();

            switch(child.getAttribute("type").getValue())
            {
                case "foo":
                    root.getFooEntities().add(ser.read(FooEntity.class, child));
                    break;
                case "bar":
                    root.getBarEntities().add(ser.read(BarEntity.class, child));
                    break;
                default:
                    // Not a Foo nor a Bar - what now!?
                    break;
            }
        }

        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, RootNode value) throws Exception
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet!");
    }
}
```

There are some things to optimize, eg. add a `root.addBar(ser.read(BarEntity.class, child))` or errorhandling in general.

Btw. instead of *two* lists, you can maintain a *single* one (if relevant). Just make a superclass for the entities. You can move the `type`-attribute to there too.

### Usage

Here's an example how to use:

```
final String input = "<RootNode>\n"
        + "    <Entities>\n"
        + "        <Entity type=\"foo\">\n"
        + "            <Price>1</Price>\n"
        + "        </Entity>\n"
        + "\n"
        + "        <Entity type=\"bar\">\n"
        + "            <URL>www.google.co.uk</URL>\n"
        + "        </Entity>\n"
        + "\n"
        + "        <Entity type=\"foo\">\n"
        + "            <Price>77</Price>\n"
        + "        </Entity>\n"
        + "    </Entities>\n"
        + "</RootNode>";


final Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy()); // <-- Note the strategy!

RootNode root = ser.read(RootNode.class, input);
System.out.println(root);
```

Nothing really spectacular here too ...

**Output:**

```
RootNode{fooEntities=[FooEntity{price=1}, FooEntity{price=77}], barEntities=[BarEntity{url=www.google.co.uk}]}
```

Comment: I was running into the very same question and found this very nice example how to handle instance generation based on an arbitrary attribute's value! One question I still have: If `RootNode` in the above example had further elements besides the `Entities`-list: can one somehow fall back to the default reading of the Simple library or is there a default `Converter` for these elements or would one have to add their handling to the `RootNodeConverter` shown? Since in my case I have quite a lot of further elements in the root node that would be very tedious...